# tSQLt Testing SQL Server security permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, tsqlt

Is there a way to test security permissions in tSQLt?

Currently I am trying to test an accounts security and the results return from tSQLt are not what I am expecting. I am expecting on error that the account does not have permissions, but it appears that the "test" is using my account permissions and succeeding.

```
EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass @ClassName = N'TestSecurity'    -- nvarchar(max)
go

CREATE PROCEDURE TestSecurity.[test execute as security]
AS 
BEGIN
    EXECUTE AS USER = 'account3'
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.User AS u
    REVERT
END 
GO 
CREATE PROCEDURE TestSecurity.[test security on WebUser]
AS 
BEGIN
    EXECUTE AS USER = 'account3'
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.WebUser AS wu
    REVERT
END 
GO 

EXEC tSQLt.Run
    @TestName = N'TestSecurity'
    --,@TestResultFormatter = N''  -- nvarchar(max)
```

Results are two table results printed and 2 successful tests:

```
(1 row affected)  
+----------------------+ 
|Test Execution Summary|
+----------------------+   '
|No|Test Case Name                           |Dur(ms)|Result |
+--+-----------------------------------------+-------+-------+ 
|1 |[TestSecurity].[test execute as security]|    257|Success|
|2 |[TestSecurity].[test security on SecUser]|     27|Success|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Test Case Summary: 2 test case(s) executed, 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 errored.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When is reality the dbo.User table should have failed and the WebUser table should succeed? I expect an error but I get results back?

The error I expect to get back should look like

```
 -- run
 EXECUTE AS USER = 'account3'   
 SELECT *   FROM dbo.WebUser AS wu

-- returns
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 4
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'WebUser', database '...', schema '...'.
```

I understand I should add tSQLt.ExpectException, but it is not even throwing an exception there are results coming back. I was trying to figure out how it is executing right now and then add the tSQLt Exception check. There is no security to return results so I am confused.

**Update 1**
Executing

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestSecurity.[test execute as security]
AS 
BEGIN
    EXECUTE AS USER = 'account3'
    -- EDIT
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.user_token AS ut

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.User AS u
    REVERT
END 
GO
```

Returns

```
name                type        usage
account3            SQL USER    GRANT OR DENY
public              ROLE        GRANT OR DENY
db_securitycheck    ROLE        GRANT OR DENY
db_executor         ROLE        GRANT OR DENY
db_webexecutor      ROLE        GRANT OR DENY
dbo                 SQL USER    AUTHENTICATOR
db_owner            ROLE        AUTHENTICATOR
```

Which kinda of makes sense except db_owner which are my permissions not the account3 permissions.

[image]

Comment: Add a `SELECT * FROM sys.user_token` inside the `EXECUTE AS ... REVERT`-block and report back what you get. (More info: https://sqlity.net/en/1778/secret-security-token-sql-server-determines-active-permissions/)

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: db_owner is listed as authenticator, not as "GRANT  OR DENY". Same for dbo. That means that account3 is not inheriting permissions  from either. One of the other roles must have the permission to access the table.

Comment: Oh yeah your are right @SebastianMeine db_owner is just authenticator. I have updated the answer with what happens when I run the same command outside of the stored procedure, just to be clear it is not inheriting these permissions at least from these roles. I wonder if it has to do with the stored procedure?

Comment: It is to do with stored procedure security. I've added an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134978/how-does-impersonation-and-security-permissions-in-tsqlt-tests-work that I think also answers this question.