# How does impersonation and security permissions in tSQLt tests work?

Tags: sql-server, testing, sql-server-2016, tsqlt

I have a tSQLt test which I expect to fail but it runs with success. When I run the code outside the procedure, it fails as expected, but when executing the test with Run, no error occurs.

I have read the question [tSQLt Testing SQL Server security permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268751/tsqlt-testing-sql-server-security-permissions) but the accepted answer does not solve my problem.

My test looks like this:

```sql
    CREATE PROCEDURE TestSecurity.[test AFDK_Reader cannot read from AWS schema]
    AS 
    BEGIN
        --EXEC tSQLt.ExpectException
        EXECUTE AS USER = 'AFDK_Reader'

        select *
        from sys.user_token

        SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions('AWS', 'SCHEMA')   
        ORDER BY subentity_name, permission_name ;   

        SELECT *
        FROM [AWS].[ADRESSEPUNKT_HISTORIK]
        REVERT
    END
```

The role has granted select permissions on the AFDK schema only and that is the only database role membership the SQL user has.

The AFDK_Reader has no permissions to read from the AWS schema.

Can anybody tell me how to get on with my debugging? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`EXECUTE AS... REVERT` commands don't behave in the way you are expecting inside a stored procedure. This is a general feature of stored procedure security in SQL Server; one common use of stored procedures is to abstract permissions. The MS docs page [Customizing Permissions with Impersonation in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/customizing-permissions-with-impersonation-in-sql-server) says:

> SQL Server does not check the permissions of the caller if the stored
>   procedure and tables have the same owner.

and that's effectively what's happening here. Even though the `EXECUTE AS` changes the security context, that security context isn't checked inside the stored procedure.

The docs page also says:

> However, ownership chaining doesn't work if objects have different
>   owners or in the case of dynamic SQL.

One way to get the behaviour you're expecting would be to run the `SELECT` statement from inside a dynamic SQL statement, which means that the active security context is tested against the table permissions:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestSecurity.[test AFDK_Reader cannot read from AWS schema]
AS 
BEGIN
    EXEC tSQLt.ExpectException
    EXECUTE AS USER = 'AFDK_Reader'

    EXEC ('SELECT * FROM [AWS].[ADRESSEPUNKT_HISTORIK]')
    REVERT
END
```

A alternative (better?) solution might be to use the built-in permission functions to test permissions settings through metadata. Here's one way, still using `EXECUTE AS... REVERT` and [`sys.fn_my_permission`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-my-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestSecurity.[test AFDK_Reader cannot read from AWS schema]
AS 
BEGIN
    EXECUTE AS USER = 'AFDK_Reader'
    DECLARE @permissionCount int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.fn_my_permissions('[AWS].[ADRESSEPUNKT_HISTORIK]', 'OBJECT') WHERE permission_name = 'SELECT' AND subentity_name = '')
    REVERT
    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals 0, @permissionCount
END
```